# Cannot get Exim to verify DANE for remote smtp

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, exim, dane

I am trying to configure Exim to try DANE before deciding to deliver unencrypted mail to remote hosts.

My general Exim configuration has: `dns_dnssec_ok = 1`.

For the `dnslookup` router: `dnssec_request_domains = *`

And for the `remote_smtp` transport:

```
hosts_try_dane = *
dnssec_request_domains = *
```

My system dns resolver verifies dnssec, `dig do.havedane.net` has the `ad` flag set.

Despite all this, `havedane.net` reports: `Email to domain with invalid DANE delivered.`

I then try requiring verification:
`hosts_require_dane = *`

This results in a failure for all three tests, for instance:

```
R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp: DANE error: do.havedane.net lookup not DNSSEC
```

I've confirmed I can get a DNSSEC validated record for `do.havedane.net` via `dig`, so why does Exim suggest otherwise?